# new package gazebo does not compile!

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I checked out today the gazebo package, from simulator_gazebo:
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk
and it does not compile! I get a lot of errors, concerning the urdf2gazebo. Here is the beginning of the error messages:

```
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/urdf2gazebo.cpp:755: error: ‘class urdf::Link’ has no member named ‘addCollision’ 
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/urdf2gazebo.cpp: In member function ‘void 
urdf2gazebo::URDF2Gazebo::printCollisionGroups(boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Link>)’:
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/urdf2gazebo.cpp:801: error: ‘class urdf::Link’ has no member named ‘collision_groups’
```

...

I reinstalled my ROS-System today, from:
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10155/new-package-gazebo-does-not-compile!/) by [Kike](https://answers.ros.org/users/600/kike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-05**:
Actually the "edit" link below your posts allows you to edit it after the fact.

**Comment by [Kike](https://answers.ros.org/users/600/kike/) on 2011-06-03**:
of course, sorry! i will keep it in mind for the next time!

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-03**:
If you don't mind, please put the error message in "code" formatting (the button is marked "101010"). It's much easier to read that way. (might want to drop the ! as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

as mentioned, trunk or development branches are not meant to be stable, but if you really want to try and run from gazebo trunk, try compiling against unstable of robot_model and see if that fixes at least part of your problem as stated?  hopefully a lot of the new features you might be looking for will be in the latest unstable release simulator_gazebo-1.3.0.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-06-05**:
what are you looking for in the trunk and also, can you try and overlay/compile gazebo trunk against ros-unstable-simulator-gazebo instead of ros-diamondback-desktop-full?

**Comment by [Kike](https://answers.ros.org/users/600/kike/) on 2011-06-03**:
ah ok, thanks! i tried the new robot_model, and it fixed the errors above! But others occur, so i will stay with the older version of gazebo for now and just exchange my needed files per hand.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The head of trunk is not necessarily compatible with anything other than the bleeding edge (other trunk heads).

If you want to use an svn copy of gazebo you should probably download the diamondback branch. That one will work with your diamondback install:

stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/diamondback/

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1